# Call custom method as Display Object AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, inheritance, reference

I have a class which extends MovieClip. This class has an update() function which needs to be called every new frame with the deltaTime in the arguments. This works if the class has been declared but not if it has just been added to the display list.
Code in the main class:

```
package packageFoo{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import packageFoo.customMovieclip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip{
        public function Main():void{
            var testMc:customMovieClip = new customMovieClip();
            addChild(testMc);
            testMc.update(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs the correct values where as if I just added it without referencing it:

```
package packageFoo{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import packageFoo.customMovieclip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip{
        public function Main():void{
            addChild(new customMovieclip());
            this.getChildAt(0).update(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

This makes the compile time error: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method update through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
I can't really reference the 'customMovieclip's because I am wanting multiple ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `this.getChildAt(0)` is not `customMovieClip`. This can arise if your `Main` has pre-places components at design time. To check, do `trace(this.numChildren)` as the first line of `Main()` constructor. And also, to address any subclass methods properly, you need to typecast your `DisplayObject` returned by `getChildAt()` to a proper type.

```
(this.getChildAt(0) as customMovieClip).update(dt);
```

Still, using a class-wide variable is better if you want to address that custom MC in more than one function of main class.

Comment: `(this.getChildAt(0) as customMovieClip)` should be treated as an anit-pattern, since it will throw a type error and hides the fact that the type cast failed. `if (this.getChildAt(0) is customMovieClip) {customMovieClip(this.getChildAt(0)).update(dt)}` is cleaner and avoids runtime errors.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic See, evenb if it's an anti-pattern, the error thrown signifies that the programmer had coded something wrong. A correct code shall never throw errors from within itself, as everything within a standalone SWF mosule is under total control of the programmer. I prefer to get a 1009 if type mismatch than find out half of my game stopped working for an undetermined reason.

Comment: `customMovieClip(this.getChildAt(0)).update(dt)` would then be even better since you get the right type of error right away. In my example the developer could respond in an else branch to the unexpected type. But ... nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid a reference to the custom class in the document class, you can call it like this:

```
this.getChildAt(0)["update"](dt);
```